# scp to remote without storing locally

Tags: scp

I have host1 and host1a on one network. And host2 and host 2a on another network. There is a file on host1a which can be only connected via host1, similarly host2s can only be connected via host2.

Host 1 and host2 can talk to each other, now I want to transfer a massive file from host1a to host2a without storing the file anywhere on host1 and host2. Is it possible? If so how?

Read from host2a, use a named pipe or something on host1 and host2 and push it all the way through to host2a
Host1a -> Host1 -> Host2 -> Host2a

Comment: See [this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/66949/scp-from-one-external-server-to-another/557074#557074)

Comment: That will take my file to host2, but I do not want the file to be stored there...How can I push it into host2a directly?

Comment: I'm sorry i can't answer you question, but you can also read [this other answer](https://superuser.com/questions/505878/creating-a-ssh-tunnel-to-transfer-files/513181#513181) or maybe post your question directly on superuser

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ProxyJump option:

`scp -o ProxyJump=user1@host1,user2@host2 file user2a@host2a:/filepath`

Comment: Perfect answer Adam, but unfortunately my scp version does not support ProxyJump. How do I rewrite this to use ProxyCommand for multiple hosts?